# How do clamp multimeter sense presences of AC voltage?

Tags: ac, electromagnetism, measurement, voltage-measurement

If a clamp meter is taken near a AC supply line, it's AC voltage sense LED starts to glow. The same coil that is used for current measurement is used to sense the presence of voltage. As far as I know CT don't produce current if there is no primary current. Same goes for Rogowski Coil from my point of view.

But it seems like that they somehow sense voltage too. I verified it in a line that has zero line current. Can anyone explain how they are sensing it?? Seems like CT or Rogowski coil may sense voltage too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But it seems like that they somehow sense voltage too. I verified it
> in a line that has zero line current. Can anyone explain how they are
> sensing it?*

The current sense coil can be regarded electrically as a plate of a capacitor and, a tiny (but measurable) current will flow from an AC line through that "plate" and through the device's handle then through your hand to ground. You can measure that current and make an estimate of the AC voltage. Of course it won't be very accurate compared to when using the coil to sense current but, it could be accurate enough to tell you that there is AC mains voltages close by (just like an electrician's neon screwdriver lights-up when touching a "live" terminal).

If the "coil" and "live" wire have a capacitance between them of about 10 pF, this is an impedance of 318 MΩ at 50 Hz. If the live wire carries 230 volts RMS, the current into the 10 pF capacitor will be 230/318 MΩ = 0.7 μA and easily measurable.